# Peer to peer video streaming

Tags: video-streaming, p2p, live-video

I am trying to develop a peer to peer application which will stream live video between the clients. The clients will be joining in and will then be able to stream.

The below code does not crash but it does not allow the streaming. Please help me as i would like to know what is the problem.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.nio.Buffer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class StreamingclienttestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    StreamingMediaPlayer smp;
    boolean paused = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Add Activity as callback for SurfaceView
        final VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

        try {
            //The IP of the streaming server and the port number
            Socket sock = new Socket("10.68.50.63",3333);

            //Get the input stream from the socket
            final InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
            if (is == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
            final File temp = File.createTempFile("mediaplayertmp", "dat",new File("/sdcard/"));
            String tempPath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
           final FileOutputStream out = null; 
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { 


            byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
            do {
                int numread = -1;
                try {
                    numread = is.read(buf);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (numread <= 0)
                    break;
                try {
                    out.write(buf, 0, numread);
                    out.equals(temp) ;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                 } while (true);


            //Start the StreamingMediaPlayer with the input stream
            smp = new StreamingMediaPlayer("temp",vv);


            //Trigger playback
            smp.play();
            } 

            }
                    ).start();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("StreamingcliettestActivity", "Exception while instantiating smp.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { 
            try {
            ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(3333);

            //Log.w(LOGTAG, "Waiting for connection");
            Socket s = ssock.accept();

            BufferedOutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(new File("sdcard/temp"));

            //Log.w(LOGTAG, "Start sending data");

            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            int read = -1;
            while ((read = fileInput.read(buff)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(buff, 0, read);
            }

            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();

            //Log.w(LOGTAG, "Closed connection");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("StreamingcliettestActivity", "Exception while instantiating smp.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    }).start();
    }


//  public class StreamingclientSERVERtestActivity extends StreamingclienttestActivity {
//      private static final String LOGTAG = "StreamingClientServer";
//      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//          setContentView(R.layout.main);




    @Override 
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newCfg) { 
        //ignore orientation change 
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newCfg); 
    } 

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        smp.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

As written, i am trying to open up a socket which reads from the input stream. I am trying to write this input stream to a file (which is being created as 0 bytes!!) but nothing in it. I am trying t use this existing stream this part to another client.

Please help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Kashif.  You are essentially asking, "please debug my program for me" without providing any evidence that you have made an honest effort to debug it yourself. You'll get a better response if you actually narrow the problem down to the problematic portion of the code and provide a smaller code sample (yet still compilable) that demonstrates the problem.